# Why does Java require PATH system variable?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I apologize if this question comes off as absurd-I am new to programming but I've been learning quickly.

Now, of course, you download the JDK as an .exe and then install it. But then you have to add a path system variable (and then it can be tested from the command prompt via javac)-but why do you have to do that? I don't know of any other software or IDE/text editor that requires the manipulation of environmental variables.

Comment: Who says you have to add a path system variable?

Comment: You have to add the path to run the software, no?

Comment: You have to know the path to run any software, yes?

Comment: But I've never had to do it when installing anything else like Eclipse or SublimeText, or any other program. I don't think I'm understanding quite how ev's work or how the Java software works.

Comment: Eclipse is **written** in Java. The only reason I ever manipulate the PATH for Java is when I need to support multiple JDKs at the same time.

Comment: It was my understanding that the installation wasn't complete until I was able to correctly run javac in the command prompt which was done by adding the path.

Comment: `c:\Program Files\Wherever\bin\javac` will run it without changing the path. Thus, doing so is a convenience for you (when you want to run that specific javac) and it is not **required**.

Comment: That’s a wrong understanding. Being able to run `javac` in the shell, is a property of the shell, so it’s the shell requiring the `PATH` variable to find `javac` when being entered without a path. When I try to run word from the command line, it won’t work out-of-the-box either. I have to specify the full path, but that doesn’t imply that my Word installation is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PATH` system variable helps to find immediately the executables you need, specifying a set of directories where executable programs are located. Or you have to specify the path where they are located.

So you don't have to add in the `PATH` each directory in your system where there are executables, but could help in same cases, for example when executables are often used by the user or used by other executables programs.

The JDK has a pletora of executable programs (e.g. `java`, `javac`, `jar`, `jstat`, etc.)  that are used very very often by developers, IDE and other tools (Maven, Ant, Ivy, etc.), so it is a best practice adding to the `PATH` the directory where JDK executables are located.

Talking about of environment variables, Java usually has other variables you should take care:

- `JAVA_HOME` - Specify the directory where your JDK is installed
- `CLASSPATH` - specifies the location where are jars, classes and packages.

Comment: I understand now-setting the PATH allows you to run things directly from the folder on the Command Pormpt for convenience. I've already set Java_Home and thank you for your patience.